# Leave a Gap between Border and JFrame

Tags: java, swing, border

I have a `JPanel` which is set to `BorderLayout`. I have added 2 `JPanels` inside this panel, one south and one center. In the center panel, i added a `LowerBevelBorder`. I am finding i am not able to leave a gap between the Main frame and the border. How do i do that? This is my `panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder());`

Comment: I don't understand your problem, can you provide an SSCCE? And possibly a screenshot of how you want it to look?

Comment: possinle with `BorderLayout(int hgap, int vgap)` http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html#BorderLayout%28int,%20int%29

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [compound border](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/border/CompoundBorder.html) which allows you to nest borders without having to create containers just for this purpose. The API can help you set this up.  e.g.,

```
int eb = 10;
panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
    BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(eb, eb, eb, eb), // outer border
    BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder()));      // inner border
```

Note code not tested.

Note also that this depends on what panel1 is. If it's not the BorderLayout main JPanel, then your best bet is to set the Border of the BorderLayout-using JPanel to be an EmptyBorder.